# Python - pint - Can I set default type to Decimal?

Tags: python, decimal, pint

Im using [pint](http://pint.readthedocs.io/) module in a project. Objects in my project handle numerical data as Decimals. When I set simple pint units to a Decimal, it works:

```
>>> import pint
>>> from decimal import Decimal as D
>>> ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()
>>> D(10) * ureg.kN
<Quantity(10, 'kilonewton')>
```

But, if I try to add a second unit, it breaks. Building kiloNewton*meters in this example:

```
>>> D(10) * ureg.kN * ureg.m
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'
```

I'm using this hack:

```
>>> a = D(1) * ureg.kN
>>> b = D(1) * ureg.m
>>> unit_kNm = a * b
>>> D(10) * unit_kNm
<Quantity(10, 'kilonewton * meter')>
```

I understand why it happens. I'm looking for a solution to set up pint as I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
>>> D(10) * (ureg.kN * ureg.m)
<Quantity(10, 'kilonewton * meter')>
```

And this too:

```
>>> Q = ureg.Quantity
>>> Q(D(10), "kN*m")
<Quantity(10, 'kilonewton * meter')>
```

Answer (score 2):

As version 0.11 of `pint`, you can create `UnitRegistry` with the `non_int_type=Decimal` options. All new quantities created with this `UnitRegistry` instance have their value represented by a `Decimal` instance.

Example:

```py
import pint
from decimal import Decimal
ureg = pint.UnitRegistry(non_int_type=Decimal)
a = ureg.Quantity("5 meter")
print(type(a.magnitude))
```

This will show that the magnitude is of type `<class 'decimal.Decimal'>`.

Answer (score 1):

Type cast it to `decimal`

```
import decimal
D(10) * ureg.kN * decimal.Decimal(ureg.m)
```

Comment: It was my first idea but:
'>>> import decimal
>>> D(10) * ureg.kN * decimal.Decimal(ureg.m)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: conversion from Unit to Decimal is not supported
''

Comment: try to convert it to `float` first then.

Comment: Doesn't work. A pint object is a unit of measure and a numerical value. You can't cast the entire object. May be another way.

Comment: try to find base class of `pint` object and then try to convert it.